# Como carregar objetos no UI no Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Olá, bom dia!
Não tenho conhecimento algum sobre o `shiny`, e estou com dificuldades quanto a executar algumas ações.

Gostaria que ele executasse uma `reactive` por meio do `selectInput`, `radioButtons`, `textInput` (não sei no caso se seria `textInput` ou `numericInput`).

O `selectInput`, selecionaria uma cultura, que no `server`, iria localizar um valor em um `data.frame`.

Tentei carregar um data.frame `CULT_F` na `ui` porém o mesmo quando eu rodava o API era carregado sua primeira linha.

O motivo de querer carregar um objeto (`data.frame`) na `ui` e que verifiquei que existe uma maneira de acrescentar valores a um data.frame rodando a API, neste caso eu poderia cadastrar alguma cultura futuramente, e a API se atualizaria, já que estaria carregando o objeto editado toda vez que rodar.

uma outra inexistência de conhecimento meu, é como fazer que no caso das listas, ou caixas de preenchimento aparecesse na frente da `label`, e não em baixo.

Por motivo que desconheço não estou conseguindo executar essas ações, gostaria se possível de um auxílio com respostas práticas, nada de apenas citar o erro que ta dando pelo programa, sem mostrar didaticamente como soluciona-lo,

desde já agradeço a boa vontade de quem puder me auxiliar!!!

segue o código, no exemplo está os data.frames usados, porém no código da `ui` eu iria usar `read.table()`.

```
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      selectInput("CULT",label="Cultura",list("Abacaxi", "Açafrão", "Alfafa", "Algodão", "Amendoim",
                                           "Azeitona", "Banana", "Batata", "Beterraba", "Café",
                                           "Cana-de-açúcar", "Cebola", "Cítricas", "Ervilha", "Feijão", 
                                           "Fumo", "Girassol", "Melância", "Milho", "Pimenta", "Repolho", 
                                           "Soja", "Sorgo", "Tomate", "Trigo", "Uva")),
#selectInput("CULT","Cultura:",c(paste(CULT_F$CULTURA,sep="")))
      radioButtons("TEXTUR", label = "Textura:", choices = list("Arenosa" = 1, "Média" = 2, "Argilosa" = 3),selected = 1),
      textInput("ETc",  "ETc (mm):" , value = "ENTER")), 
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("Dados_Solos"))),

server = function(input, output) {

  CULT_F<-structure(list(
    GRUPO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
              3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
              4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), 
    CULTURA = structure(c(12L, 20L, 8L, 7L, 21L, 26L, 14L, 24L, 
                          3L, 15L, 13L, 5L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 25L, 
                          4L, 19L, 6L, 2L, 23L, 22L,  9L, 11L, 16L, 10L),
                        .Label = c("Abacaxi", "Açafrão", "Alfafa", "Algodão", "Amendoim",
                                   "Azeitona", "Banana", "Batata", "Beterraba", "Café",
                                   "Cana-de-açúcar", "Cebola", "Cítricas", "Ervilha", "Feijão", 
                                   "Fumo", "Girassol", "Melância", "Milho", "Pimenta", "Repolho", 
                                   "Soja", "Sorgo", "Tomate", "Trigo", "Uva"), class = "factor")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))

GRUP_F<-structure(list(GRUPO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), ETC = c(2L, 3L, 
                                                                                      4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                                                                      10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                      7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), FATORF = c(0.5, 0.425, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.225, 
                                                                                                                   0.2, 0.2, 0.175, 0.675, 0.575, 0.475, 0.4, 0.35, 0.325, 0.275, 
                                                                                                                   0.25, 0.225, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.45, 0.425, 0.375, 0.35, 0.3, 
                                                                                                                   0.875, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.425, 0.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            -36L))  
TEXTURA<-structure(list(TEXTU = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Arenosa", 
                                                                    "Argilosa", "Média"), class = "factor"), COD = 1:3, VIB = c(26L, 
                                                                                                                                18L, 12L), CC = c(16L, 18L, 24L), PMP = c(7L, 9L, 12L), ZE = c(20L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             30L, 40L), DA = c(1, 1.3, 1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -3L))


  SOLinput<-reactive({
   ETC<-ifelse(input$ETc<=2,2,
             ifelse(input$ETc>2 & input$ETc<=3,3,
                   ifelse(input$ETc>3 & input$ETc<=4,4,
                             ifelse(input$ETc>4 & input$ETc<=5,5,
                                   ifelse(input$ETc>5 & input$ETc<=6,6,
                                            ifelse(input$ETc>6 & input$ETc<=7,7,
                                                   ifelse(input$ETc>7 & input$ETc<=8,8,
                                                         ifelse(input$ETc>8 & input$ETc<=9,9,
                                                                ifelse(input$ETc>9,10,"ERRO_ETC")))))))))


        CULT<-CULT_F[CULT_F$CULTURA==input$CULT,]$GRUPO
        FF<-GRUP_F[GRUP_F$GRUPO==CULT & GRUP_F$ETC==ETC,]$FATORF
        DSOL<-TEXTURA[TEXTURA$COD==input$TEXTUR,]

        DTA<-((DSOL$CC-DSOL$PMP)/10)*DSOL$DA                                           # Disponibilidade Total de água: DTA (mm cm^-1)
        CTA<-DTA*DSOL$ZE                                                               # Capaciadade Total de Água: CTA, (mm cm^-1) 
        CRA<-ifelse(CTA*FF>0,ifelse(CTA*FF<1,1,CTA*FF))     # Conteúdo real de água: CRA, (mm)
        IRN<-CRA 
       cbind(data.frame(Cultura=input$CULT,FatorF=FF),DSOL,data.frame(DTA=DTA,CTA=CTA,CRA=CRA,IRN=IRN))
       })

  output$Dados_Solos<-renderTable({SOLinput()})
  })
```